# I have a 4 yr old MacBook  and screen that has started to "bleed" into the viewing area

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I'm in college (poor),  I have a 4 yr old MacBook that has started to "bleed" into the viewing area of the screen making it difficult to see.

Will Apple replace this or do I have to buy a new one?
What other options do I have without spending a fortune?

Comment: Can you upload an image to help demonstrate your issue?

Answer (score 3):

Apple will not generally pay for any repairs at the 4 year point in a product, but taking it in and asking is the only way to know.

You would be out some time, but have a quote for a paid repair as well as an explanation on exactly what is happening to the screen and whether it is something one time damaging or something that you can expect to get worse. You also have the option of taking it to a nearby computer repair man, just phone them fist to see if they can repair Apple products.

If you are broke you can try to do it your self using an online how to, I will not link to one as I do not reccomend this as you can end up doing even more damage.

Comment: I have been offered covered repairs on very rare occasions when Apple engineering wants back certain failures, but that was clearly a special case and generally related to failures of newly released products - not something that has been out for years and has a well defined service history. You can find repair guides at http://ifixit.com but LCD repairs are some of the hardest and most delicate to complete. Consider the cost of making things worse before embarking on a DIY - especially if the display is inside a unibody enclosure.